# How to make jQuery Accordion a bit cleaner?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, accordion

Using jQuery UI I created an accordion like so:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content"
    });
});
```

with this html:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h5>First header</h5>
    <div class="some_class"></div>
    <h5>Second header</h5>
    <div class="some_other_class"></div>
</div>
```

which looks like this (excluding the New Ticket button):

[image]

I now want the accordion headers to look more like the button: a white background and black text, but I'm kinda lost in where I should edit/add css.

Does anybody know how I can easily change the background and the text color of this accordion? All tips are welcome!

Comment: add a fiddle demo do you want your first header and second header like the new ticket

Comment: Are you aware of: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/

Comment: Okay, so is there no easy way to ONLY change the background without using full themes? I want to keep some control over what I'm doing. Otherwise I need to start building an accordion manually, which is not really my intention..

Comment: Well its controlled by CSS so you can override the theme; http://jsfiddle.net/alexk/5ZS2v/

Answer (score 1):

You can always add css styling just for the children of a particular DOM element. eg:

```
div#accordion h5 {
    ... custom styles ...
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7bz25/)

This does, however, mean that you must overwrite some/all of the default goodness you get from using `jqueryui`. If you only want to apply styles to a **specific** element, *right-click->Inspect element* to see the exact name of the DOM tag you want to restyle.

UPDATE: Moving the `span` around is just as easy, [see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7bz25/1/).

Doing just `#accordion span { left:0; }` may be sufficient for your purpose. If not, keep in mind...

DISCLAIMER: I do **not** recommend doing it as I have in the fiddle. Specifically this line:

```
background-position: -36px -20px;
```

is VERY hard to read, and anyone looking at your CSS without being familiar with jQueryUI's styling themes will wonder what you did. A better solution would be to outright replace the `background-image` in your `span`s with a custom one, or or even get rid of them with `display:none;` and put in your own customised icons.

Comment: Awesome! That works great! Just one more question; I would like to move the triangle-icon all the way to the left so that it touches the left border. I tried inserting `padding: 0px;`, but that only moves the title to the left. So would you know how to move the icon to the left?